calculating running totals with multiple rows to be consolidated first or the running total would be wrong
SELECT
    pph.accnt_code,
    pph.period, 
    SUM(pph.value_debit) AS debits,
    SUM(pph.value_credit) AS credits,
    SUM(pph.value_debit-pph.value_credit) OVER (ORDER BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period) AS endbal
    FROM trans_tst pph
    GROUP BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period 
    ORDER BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period

result should have beenresulting running totals table
but result obtained was
wrong running total calculation
I created an intermediate table consolidating debits and credits by period and then the running total is correct

Need to resolve a query where transaction are grouped by accnt and quarter, and get the aggregate result of debits - credits for each grouped quarter

Please include that data as a Markdown table instead of images in an [edit] - the use of images is generally discouraged.

The point to realize here is that the window functions evaluate after GROUP BY.  As a result of this, the credit and debit columns are not even available.  You should be summing the sums, using SUM() as a window function for the former.
SELECT
    pph.accnt_code,
    pph.period, 
    SUM(pph.value_debit) AS debits,
    SUM(pph.value_credit) AS credits,
    SUM(SUM(pph.value_debit) - SUM(pph.value_credit))
        OVER (ORDER BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period) AS endbal
FROM trans_tst pph
GROUP BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period 
ORDER BY pph.accnt_code, pph.period;


@Jorge also highly recommend enabling the (default since 5.7.5, 10 years ago) ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode, that prevents mistakes like yours

Problem was solved with the following code
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT
accnt_code,
period,
SUM(value_debit) over(PARTITION BY accnt_code, period) AS debit,
SUM(value_credit) over(PARTITION BY accnt_code, period) AS credit,
SUM(value_debit-value_credit) OVER(ORDER BY accnt_code, period) AS endbal

FROM trans_tst )
SELECT accnt_code, period, debit, credit, endbal
FROM cte1
GROUP BY accnt_code, period
ORDER BY accnt_code, period;
